# Need and purpose of `()` and `in` in ocaml code

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to understand Ocaml and running following code from [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/coreexamples.html#sec17):

```
let rec fib n =  
  if n < 2 then 1 else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2);;
let main () =
  let arg = int_of_string Sys.argv.(1) in
  print_int (fib arg);
  print_newline ();
  exit 0;;
main ();;
```

However, I cannot understand why `()` and `in` are needed and why following code (which is much cleaner) does not work:

```
let rec fib n =
  if n < 2 then 1 else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2);;
let main =
  let arg = int_of_string Sys.argv.(1);
  print_int (fib arg);
  print_newline;
  exit 0;;  (* Line 7. Error is coming from here.*)
main;;
```

Above code gives following error:

```
File "fib_simpler.ml", line 7, characters 8-10:
Error: Syntax error
```

I notice that removing `()` only give warning, while removing `in` gives error and program execution stops.

Keeping `in` and `()` after print_newline removes all warnings and errors. So `()` is not really needed with `main` keywords.

Above is shown in comments below:

```
let rec fib n =  (*(n) also works here*)
  if n < 2 then 1 else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2);;
let main () =  (*removing () here does not matter*)
  let arg = int_of_string Sys.argv.(1) in (* in keyword is essential here*)
  print_int (fib arg);
  print_newline ();  (*removing () causes warning *)
  exit 0;;
main ();;      (*removing () here does not matter*)
```

Any explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml is an expression-based language. It does not have statements, and therefore `;` is not a statement terminator, but a sequence operator (similar to the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) of C). `<expr1>; <expr2>` is approximately just a short-hand for `let () = <expr1> in <expr2>`. It evaluates `expr1`, discards its value, then evaluates `expr2` and returns that value.

`let <pattern> = <expr1> in <expr2>` is an expressions which binds the result of `expr1` according to `<pattern>`, which may just be a simple identifier or a more complex record pattern for example, in the context of `expr2`. The bindings created by `<pattern>` will not exist outside `expr2`.

Using `()`, called "unit" in a binding defines a function. If you omit the argument, you're not defining a function, just a value. The difference is that a value is evaluated immediately, and just once, while a function will be evaluated when it is "called" by applying arguments to it. A function that expects `()` as an argument must be given `()` as the argument to execute it, otherwise you're just passing the function itself around. And if you're just discarding it, as you do above, that is almost always an error. Hence the warning.

**In short:**

- `let arg = int_of_string Sys.argv.(1); ...` without an `in` separating two expressions is a syntax error. The compiler just doesn't realize it until it gets to the end of the current expression and discovers there is no `in` to be found there.
- `let main () =`... defines a function
- `let main = ...` defines a value
- `print_newline (); ...` applies the argument `()` to `print_newline`, thereby executing it, then discards the return value
- `print_newline; ...` doesn't really do anything

Finally, if you're just going to execute `main` once, you can reduce

```
let main () = ...;;
main;;
```

to

```
let () = ...;;
```

You don't need a named function unless you're going to use it multiple times.

Comment: Very well explained. For multiple expressions, should we do exp1 in exp2 in exp3 or exp1 in (exp2 in exp3) ?

Comment: Chaining multiple expressions just like that doesn't really make sense in general, and `in` is not a standalone keyword. Expressions evaluate into values, and you should generally keep those values for later use. The "proper" way to do this is to use `let ... in`, e.g. `let a = 2 in let b = a + a in ...` and so on. The exception is when you call functions that exhibit side-effects, like printing to the console. But even if that's all they do, they still return a value, typically `()`. And so to chain these you can do `let () = print_newline () in let () = print_endline "something" in ...`.

Comment: Or you can use the equivalent and more convenient  sequence operator, as you do above: `print_newline (); print_endline "something"; ...`